# Upadate Elastic Beanstalk environment and ebextensions files

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

I have an elastic beanstalk environment that the first upload I used with ebextensions to configure all the configurations.

Now, If I want to update the environment again (only change the code) the ebextensions stay the same,
I need to insert the ebextensions into the zip file that I  upload to update the beanstalk environment?

Or I can ignore the ebextensions and upload the zip as is?

I create the zip file using Visual Studio and I put the ebextensions inside the code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what is in your `.ebextensions`. For example, if you just install some rpm packages, then they will still be installed. But generally you would always include the config files anyway, as EB can deploy your application to new instances and then entire configuration has to be re-done from scratch.

Comment: I'm using them to set configurations like security group, HTTP redirect, or type of deployment.
If I understand you correctly, basically I need to upload them again because if one of the immutable deployments uploads the project again it needs the ebextensions because it creates a new instance.

Comment: @GalEl Yes, but there are many other reasons why EB can spin up new instance. Examples are scaling events, AZ re-balancing, instance fail-over due to hardware failure.